# Where can I find a simple Node.js Facebook app example?

Tags: facebook, node.js

I have searched everywhere but could not find the following:

A simple example web app which is built using Node.js and uses Facebook Connect to run some API calls, for example to extract the connected user wall posts.

I tried building one myself but because most Node.js/FB Connect addons/libs are dated or flawed (and also because I am new to Node) it did not work!

Answer (score 7):

You might be interested in [Facebook/Heroku sample app -- Node.js](https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-nodejs) <- GitHub source code

Read more on [Getting Started with Your Facebook App on Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook)
(22 September 2011)

Answer (score 2):

Just starting here so I can't upvote Chris' answer, but +1 for the Heroku sample app on Github.  The sample app is actually the same code you get when you create a hosted app on Heroku (which is free to start).

I did the following, following along from here(http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook):

- followed the Heroku blog entry directions to create a sample app on FB
- chose Heroku cloud hosting (free to get started)
- followed directions to download Heroku git repo of the project it creates, and also to - install the Heroku CLI tools
- created a dev version of my app on FB and configured my Heroku app to point to that apps ID and SECRET key

I also had to upgrade my Ruby to > 1.8.7 (which I was at), so I used RVM to go to 1.9.2.  You need this to install and run the 'foreman' Ruby gem, which Heroku uses to launch apps in dev mode.  So, make sure you have a late enough ruby, then 'gem install foreman'

I also had to actually run 'npm install' on the Heroku project directory to pull down all the required packages, which the blog entry above doesn't mention.

After this, which is really simple, you have a basic express app that will authenticate as you and run both on Heroku and localhost.  Heroku is prod and public, and when you do 'git push origin master' it deploys immediately, so work in dev and deploy only when ready for others to see your work.

Then you can start playing around with the sample app and it wasn't hard for me to understand the API integration, socket.io raising events on node side and event handlers in the client JS which are bound with JQuery to DOM elements to populate the data from the API to the page.  And I hadn't really worked with any of this before -- but there isn't that much code and you can restart the app from the shell, look in the browser, see what's happening and figure it out.

Good way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Closest one I am familiar with is [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth), but it just does fairly basic FB integration for OAuth2 authentication, but that is most of the heavy lifting you need to get your access token with the proper scope so you can then make an API call to post to a user's wall or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but the one that Facebook has on there site is [facebook-node-sdk](https://github.com/amachang/facebook-node-sdk). It's fairly straight forward and easy to use

Answer (score -2):

The instructions for creating a development version are in the sample app.. Readme.md. Package json shows the dependencies (async, ejs, express, faceplate) which are a good place to start .. http://expressjs.com/guide.html